# Is it problematic or a poor practice to name a field in a model 'date' in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

For example, a date field on the transaction model leads to `transaction.date`.

Will this cause any problems?

Can it make the code less readable and therefore be a poor practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call it "date". I don't think it will cause any trouble.
However, like "created_at", "updated_at" for times, is it a good idea to name a date field as "xxx_on"?

Answer (score 1):

If your transaction completes in 24 hours, you are fine with just keeping one date column. :)

It depends on what information you would like to store. A datetime column usually tells what that date/time is about. Something created/updated? As in your case consider this. A transaction will have a started_at, completed_at, failed_at etc...

Comment: Actually, I just made up transaction as an example of a model that needs a `date`. Maybe something that was more `date` and less `datetime` would have been better...

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not cause problems. It is not a reserved word, and it is not poor practice.